# Non-regular Grid-like structure with flexible sizing of items

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Template` that is a `List<List<Location>>`. Each `List<Location>` is a row and each `Location` is a column. Each row is centered, with the `Locations` at a fixed width (i.e., the locations themselves don't stretch). Since the rows have different numbers of columns (not to mention the list having a variable number of rows), This is not a simple actual "grid".

[image]

The empty spots are where some cells have been "turned off". You'll also notice that cells can be portrait or landscape.

Currently the style of the cells has them at a fixed size; I'm also including the rows/columns template here:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="imageLocationStyle">
    <!--Default styling (Portrait, Active)-->
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource fullLong}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource fullShort}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Landscape}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource fullShort}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource fullLong}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type data:ImageTemplate}">
    <!--Rows-->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageLocations}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--Columns-->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <!--Single cell-->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--Each presenter of a Template will provide its own
                                DataTemplate for TemplateImageLocation, which will
                                determine how each cell is rendered.-->
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want the cells (and thus the template) to be of variable, flexible size, relative to the size of the `Template`'s container element. The example above is cut from a `UniformGrid` that contains `Button`s, which as you can see by the selection, fill their container. I've set the xaml properties `fullLong` and `fullShort` to a set number which is untenable, not only because any other time I want to use a template in another context I'd have to define a new style with another relatively arbitrary fixed number, but because screen sizes are different not to mention template sizes are different.

I've tried using a `UniformGrid` for the template (1 column) and each row (1 row), but then all rows are the same width, which is not what I want.

I've thought about padding all the rows with the max number of cells (happens to be 7), but as far as I can imagine, that wouldn't account for the difference between portrait and landscape. A row with 7 portrait cells should take up less horizontal space than a row with 7 landscape cells.

I believe if I simply had a way to determine the `long` and `short` dimensions as a percentage of their container, everything else would work fine. If I wanted a template to stretch to fill all or most available space depending on the size of the template itself (number of cells), I'd need to figure out the length of the longest row and/or column to determine what the percentage should even be.

How can this be done? Do I need to do all the calculations in a viewmodel and bind styles to that? How would I put all of it together?

Comment: Use a Canvas as ItemsPanel.

Comment: Want to make sure I understand this correctly. You want to scale this layout up or down uniformly, so that the longest row fills the width of the container, right? And what about the height? If the layout doesn't have enough vertical space, should it shrink, clip or scroll?

Comment: @KeithStein it should shrink. Great question thanks.

Comment: @Clemens ItemsPanel for the rows? The locations (cells)? Both? I think the real difficult part is the size of the cells.

Comment: The ratio of height/width of each cell is constant, right? (Ignoring the portrait/landscape orientation). So all the landscape cells should be one size and all the portrait cells will be one size?

Comment: A single ItemsControl with a Canvas as ItemsPanel. Calculate the locations in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an interesting problem. I think using nested `ItemsControl`s was the right approach- it was my first thought before I saw your code- but I think your requirements are a bit too complicated for that. You're going to need to go custom; a custom control.

It's a bit of work, but I think it's the "right" way to do things, plus it's good experience in my opinion.

### Base Type

I thought maybe a [custom panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element) would be the right fit. [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel) is the base class for "containers" which "position and arrange child objects". And that is exactly what you need, a custom arrangement of child objects. Implementing a custom `Panel` also gives you access everything you need, specifically the [`MeasureOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride) method, which gives you `availableSize`, telling you how much space you have to work with. It also lets you dictate a size for each child element, which you can calculate based off `availableSize` and the number of children.

The problem is `Panel`s generally support adding any kind of visual content, and the content you want to display is restricted to a specific data structure. I also thought of a custom `ItemsControl`, but we get the same problem. `ItemsControl`s are designed to be independent of the `ItemsPanel` that they use.

For this reason, I think you should just inherit from `FrameworkElement`. It's one level down from `Panel` and still includes `MeasureOverride`.

### Data Source Property

For your data, you need to end up with an `IList<IList<Location>>`. I recommend using `IList<T>` over `List<T>` so as not to restrict the input type unnecessarily. This will allow for `List<T>`, but also other collections like `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Since you will only be expecting input of that type, there's no real need to implement a flexible input property like `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. You should, however, do the following:

- Include a [`PropertyChangedCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback) so you will be notified when the data source changes. This way you know to invalidate the current layout of the control.
- In the `PropertyChangedCallback`, check if the `IList<T>` provided also implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (such as `ObservableCollection<T>`). If so, attach a handler to the [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged) for the same reason as above. Make sure to remove the existing handler if the data source property is given a new value.

### Item Elements

Each `Location` needs a visual item to represent it. I would recommend sticking with `ContentControl` (this is what the base `ItemsControl` uses). You would create the `ContentControl` in code-behind whenever a new item is added, and dispose of the control if an item is removed.

You can even add an `ItemTemplate` property to the class to allow for a dynamic `DataTemplate`- or you build the template in code-behind if you want to restrict it.

You would keep track of which `Location` belongs to which `ContentControl` using a `Dictionary<Location, ContentControl>`. If you need two-way lookup, you can have a second `Dictionary<ContentControl, Location>` or just use a single `List<(Location, ContentControl)>`.

You will need to override [`GetVisualChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.getvisualchild) and [`VisualChildrenCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.visualchildrencount) as shown in the linked documentation. You will add/remove the `ContentControl`s to/from the custom control by calling [`AddVisualChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.addvisualchild) and [`RemoveVisualChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visual.removevisualchild?view=netcore-3.1) (an example can be seen in the linked documentation).

### Layout Methods

The full rundown on the WPF layout system can be found here: [MSDN - Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout)

Now we get to the important bit, actually laying out the `Location` items. When WPF is ready to show your control, or when the available space changes, it will call your [`MeasureOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride) and [`ArrangeOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride) methods.

In `MeasureOverride`, you'll need to do the following:

1. **Find the longest row and the longest column to determine "base size"**
   You'll need to loop through each item for this. We're look for longest as in visual size, not number of items.
   At this stage, we don't know the scale of the items yet, so we measure in terms of aspect ratio. The items in your question appear to be 4:3 when landscape and 3:4 when portrait, so I'll use that. This means when calculating the length of a row, you add a `4` for every landscape item, and a `3` for every portrait item. For columns it's the reverse, since we're measuring height instead of width.
   Create a [`Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.size) variable where `Width` is the the length of the longest row and `Height` is the length of the longest column. This will be called `baseSize`- its the size of the control before any scaling.
2. **Compare `baseSize` with `availableSize` to determine the scaling factor**
   You want to get the ratio of the available width to your base width, and the availalbe height to your base height. This gets you your scaling factor. Since you want to scale uniformly and never exceed `availableSize`, you take whichever of these ratios is smallest.

```
//I hope this math is right, it's getting late
double scale = Math.Min(availableSize.Width / baseSize.Width,  availableSize.Height / baseSize.Height);
```

3. **Calculate the size for a scaled item**
   Since all items are the same size, there's no scene recalculating the size for every one. Do it once to save processing power.

```
//This will probably be some private constant somewhere in the class
Size baseLandscape = new Size(4, 3);
Size basePortrat = new Size(baseLandscape.Height, baseLandscape.Width);

//Scaling the items to available space
Size scaledLandscape = new Size(baseLandscape.Width * scale, baseLandscape.Height * scale);
Size scaledPortrait = new Size(basePortrat.Width * scale, basePortrat.Height * scale);
```

4. **Call `Measure` for each child item**
   Loop through the `Dictionary` or `List` from the *Item Elements* section again. Take each `ContentControl` and call `Measure`. Pass `scaledLandscape` if the item is to be displayed landscape, or `scaledPortrait` if it is to be displayed portrait. This tells each item how big it is allowed to be.
5. **Return the desired size of the overall control**
   The last thing to do is to let WPF know how big our control wants to be. This is easy enough to get. It's just out `baseSize` from earilier, multiplied by our `scale`:

```
return new Size(baseSize.Width * scale, baseSize.Height * scale);
```

Next is `ArrangeOverride`, where you actually position your newly-measured items internally. In this method, you'll need to loop through all your items one final time, in row-then-column order. The size of each item will be new be available via `ContentControl.DesiredSize`.

Declare a `double YOffset = 0`, you'll need it later.

For each row:

1. Take the height if the tallest item, that will be the row's height.
2. Add up the width of every item, that will be the row's width.
3. Take `finalSize.Width` and subtract the width of the row. This gives you the amount of extra space. Since you want to center reach row, take this number and divide it by 2. We'll call this final number `XOffset`.
4. Loop through each `ContentControl` in the row and call `Arrange`. Pass it a `Rect` with `X = XOffset`, `Y = YOffset`, and `Height` and `Width` equal the `ContentControl`'s `DesiredSize`. After each item, increment `XOffset` by the width of that item.
5. This row is done. Increment `YOffset` by the height of the row (from step 1) and move to the next row.

### Conclusion

That's most of what you'll need. I've written more than I expected, but I like these kinds of challenges, so it was fun. I hope you give it a try instead of just using my second answer. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Hey, if this ended up working for you, please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Actually, I think I've got it working a lot simpler. I have the `MaxRowLength` and `SizeRatio` (longside : shortside) in my viewmodel. And then everything else is calculated in the view using multibinding converters Basically, the bindings say: `width = actualWidth / MaxRowLength; height = actualWidth / MaxRowLength / SizeRatio`.

Comment: I will also note that I've wound up deciding to ignore the size of the current template, by which I mean that the cell size will always be the same (small) no matter how many rows or columns I have.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to my complicated, "right way" answer (which I still hope you read). You might be able to get by by just wrapping your top `ItemsControl` in a [`ViewBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox). You can use this control to visually scale the contents uniformly. I'm not sure how clean it will look, but it is definitly simpler than doing the math to calculate the correct size of each item.