# Pass control to binding by value

Tags: wpf

I have a converter that I use to determine the size of a child element based on the size of its container (parent).

```xml
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=rowsContainer, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource sizer}}"/>
```

```cs
public class CellSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly int _maxNum = 7;
    private readonly int _margin = 0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        double width = (double)value;
        return (width / _maxNum) - _margin;
    }
}
```

This works, and when I resize my window, the size of the components change. Hooray!

I want to factor in the height as well, so I've tried passing in the control itself and getting its properties inside the converter:

```xml
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ElementName=rowsContainer, Converter={StaticResource sizer}}"/>
```

```cs
public class CellSizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly int _maxNum = 7;
    private readonly int _margin = 0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        ItemsControl rowsContainer = (ItemsControl)value;
        return (rowsContainer.ActualWidth / _maxNum) - _margin;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this the size never changes. It seems like the control gets passed to the converter once but never updates. I imagine it has something to do with passing by reference rather than passing by value. Or something like that.

I know I can pass multiple values into the converter using a `MultiBinding` and an `IMultiValue Converter` but since all that values I'd want are already wrapped up in a nice little object (the control) it would be so much cleaner in my xaml to just bind it this way.

How can I pass the control such that it updates?

Comment: "How can I pass the control such that it updates?" - there is no way to do it with Binding

Answer (score 1):

The converter only gets called when the property that you actually bind to is set to a new value.

This means that you cannot bind to the `rowsContainer` control itself as it never gets when the `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` property is updated.

A `MultiBinding` to both `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` is the way to go here.

> How can I pass the control such that it updates?

You can't for the reason already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the control gets passed to the converter once but never updates. I imagine it has something to do with passing by reference rather than passing by value.

Property updates in WPF aren't magic, code has to explicitly call into WPF to tell it a value has been updated.

When you bind `ActualWidth`, that's actually a dependency property that has a changed event WPF can hook into and be notified by the code changing it. However, when you bind the control itself, that is not a dependency property, and the control doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so WPF never knows its properties have changed.

> I know I can pass multiple values into the converter using a MultiBinding and an IMultiValue Converter but [...]

A `MultiBinding` allows you to bind to multiple dependency properties and have WPF listen to all their property change notifications at once. I stopped the quote at "but" because it doesn't matter what comes after, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Though I will point out that what you're doing is very counter-intuitive, it's the job of the layout to position and size your controls. Instead of playing with bindings on size, either find a system layout that does the job, or write one yourself. It will be much cleaner and much, much more efficient.

Comment: If I add code examples with more context, would you give an example of how to "write one myself"? Although it's clear that `MultiBinding` is the way to go to with my current implementation, it still actually seems pretty "clean", at least compared to a long answer to my problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275430/6826164

Comment: You might be confusing "clean" with "simple". It's simpler to use bindings, sure. Inefficient, bulky, un-scalable, but simple. A layout requires no bindings and it's one-pass (whereas your bindings are invalidating the layout so it actually runs at least twice), you just have to sit down and write it.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely unscalable, I can see at least that much and definitely take your word on the others. If I post more code would you give an example?

Comment: Well, looking at what the converter is actually doing, it seems you want to divide one space into 7 and put an element in each? You should just use a `Grid`.

Comment: That's not really it. Up to 7 cells can be in each row, and each cell can be portrait or landscape. Because cells abut next to each other, it's not about dividing the row into equal spaces. A Grid for each row would require dynamically determining the grid column definitions and width. Honestly, as I was searching for that I came upon some other things that inspired me to take this current direction first.

Comment: A `WrapPanel` then, that sounds like exactly what you're describing. Though to be clear that's not what your code is doing, it's dividing the parent width by a `readonly int` (should be `const int`) equal to 7, so it always divides the whole parent width in 7.

Comment: The issue is that *somewhere* I need to specify the width and height of a cell. If it were always landscape then I could just divide the space evenly. But because of the different rotations I need to define a "long side length" and a "short side length". The entire "grid" (a `Template`) will be displayed in variously-sized containers so it's unreasonable to define a hard-coded length for each container, especially accounting for different screen sizes. That's why I'm looking for a way to scale a value, to be used in the layout, to the size of the container.

Comment: A properly constructed cell, whatever it is, should define its own size. And if you throw it in a `WrapPanel` it will arrange the items together without changing their desired sizes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216223/discussion-between-jonathan-tuzman-and-blindy).